# Resizing Map width and height (avoid distortion)

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, react

I am working with OpenLayers library on React

**My first question** is how to avoid distortion while resizing map width and height,

**The second issue** is when I am changing with/height each time it creates a new map.
I know that issue is happening because of initializing new Map each time.

**How can resize map without initializing new Map?**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import { layers_collection, vw } from '../map - constants/map-tools';
import { Button, Input, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import MapSource from './map-source';

const initMap = () => {
   return (new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: layers_collection,
      view: vw,
   }));
};

var map = initMap()

const OpenLayerMap = () => {
   const [currentWidth, setWidth] = useState<string>("400")

   useEffect(() => {
      initMap()
      map.updateSize()
   });


   return (
      <>
         <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
               setWidth("400")
         }}>
            400
      </Button>
         <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
               setWidth("800")
         }} >
            800
     </Button>
         <div id="map" style={{width: `${currentWidth}px`}} >
            <MapSource />
         </div>
      </>
   );
};

export default OpenLayerMap;
```

Comment: Why do you call `initMap` and `updateSize` at the same time? You only need to call `updateSize` when the container size of the map changes.

Comment: Thank you for responding,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved that issue, the init map is related through use effect, I just give a condition for an initialising map at once and update map size each time**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import { layersCollections, view } from '../map - constants/map-tools';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import MapSource from './map-source';
var map: ol.Map;

const initMap = () => {
   map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: layersCollections,
      view: view,
   });
};


const OpenLayerMap = () => {
   const [currentWidth, setWidth] = useState<number | string>(800)
   const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState<boolean>(false);


   useEffect(() => {
      if (isMounted) {
         map.updateSize()
      } else {
         setIsMounted(true);
         initMap()
      }
   },
   );
   return (
      <>
         <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
            setWidth(400)
         }}
          size = "small">
            400
      </Button>
         <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
            setWidth(800) 
         }} 
         size = "small"
         >
            800
     </Button>

         <div id="map" style={{ height: 400, width: currentWidth }}>
            <MapSource />
         </div>
      </>
   );
};

export default OpenLayerMap;
```